# Receiving mime type error with my deployed angular application

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, web-applications

after updating my angular application from 13 to 16 im experiencing the following error:

[image: Browser Error]

Everything is running on my server in a docker container. All necessary files (index.html, main..js, ...) are located in /use/share/nginx/html/.

My nginx config looks like:

[image: Nginx]

and my index.html base href should be set correctly like this:

[image: index.html]

and as you can see in the browser it opens the correct index.html. The files main, polyfill and runtime are on the same folder as the index.html which should be the root folder. I am totally confused why I get this error and I tried almost everything I found in related questions.

Can someone help me to find out the problem?

I tried different settings in the angular.json and the base href but I could not get any insights in the problem

Comment: Can someone at least provide me some hints how I can debug the situation? Or What's is possibly wrong?

Comment: Hi there, please upload error message and codes in the plain text format.